# Chrome timeline tab explanation

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline) says:

> Note that the first event, Send Request (Calendar.html) is shown with a bar that consists
>   of three shades of blue. The darkest one marks the time that the event itself took, the 
>   next     one corresponds to the CPU time that this event along with all the nested events
>   took (here,     it includes Receive Response, Receive Data and so on), and the palest bar
>   stands for the wall time between the start of the first event and the end of the last event.

What exactly is meant by `the start of the first event and the end of the last event`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just expand the *"Send Request (Calendar.html)"* event, and you will understand what that means :-) The `Send Request` event will have associated asynchronous sub-events, the last of which is usually `Finish Loading`. So, the total time between you sent the request ("send request") and received all its data ("finish loading"), which is the "wall clock" time, is shown by the most pale bar.

On the opposite, the second-pale bar just shows the total time of an events and all its sub-events (imagine stacking the event's darkest bar and all its sub-events' darkest bars on top of each other).

Comment: Would you mind if I ask you to elaborate your answer? As for me the problem from the question is still unresolved. I still do not understand what is for the different rates of "paleness". Also what do they mean when the glue mode is on/off ? And how to treat the fact that your explanation does not correspond to the docs (which in its own turn is extremely unclear): https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/timeline#coloring_of_timeline_records_with_nested_events

Comment: As I can assume a non-pale part of a bar is for **CPU time** of a parent event and all its synchronous children. A paler part of a bar (which usually appears in a middle of a bar) + non-pale part is for **CPU time** of a parent event and all its children (synchronous and asynchronous). And the palest part + two other parts (mentioned before) is for **"wall clock" time** of a parent event and all its children.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Our online docs might be a bit out-of-date, but this should be fixed sooner or later.

Comment: Could you please take a look at my question as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23961458/how-to-read-chrome-timeline