# How to read Chrome Timeline?

Tags: google-chrome, performance-testing, developer-payload

Google Chrome browser has a Timeline tab in the developer panel which shows how long it takes to render a page.

But I do not understand why it shows 17s while the page completes rendering within 4s.
The start and end points of the measurement seems to be off. Is there an explanation of this measurement behavior?[image]

Comment: Note that it begins timing the moment you hit Record, not the moment you refresh the page.

Comment: I didn't hit record. When you don't hit Record, it will automatically start and stop recording as the page reloads.

Comment: Nevertheless, it seems pretty clear that it was recording before you hit refresh.

Comment: Indeed, I hit F5 back to back, and the Timeline does not change. If it has been recording since the moment the tab was started, the total #s must change cumulatively.

Comment: Roughly at the 17 sec mark I can see a _beforeunload_ event handler, which means it's the moment when you navigated away from the page for which the timeline was started.